# Check if Python's http.server has finished starting

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, automated-tests

I have a test suite for a script that uses Python's http.server module. The test suite spawns a new server instance for each test case (using subprocess.Popen), then makes various requests and checks the results.

However, sometimes the server doesn't finish starting in time, and all of the requests end in connection errors.

I have a method for detecting if the server has started that works on some computers but not others:

```
self.server = subprocess.Popen(args)

# Wait for server to finish starting
for _ in range(10):
    try:
        with socket.create_connection(('127.0.0.1', port or 8000)): break
    except ConnectionRefusedError:
        time.sleep(0.1)
else:
    raise Exception('Port {} not responding. Did the server fail to start?'.format(port or 8000))
```

However this only works on my higher-spec computer. On a lower spec computer (same OS, same Python version etc.), the server is still not ready after the snippet above runs. Adding sleeps afterward helps some, but isn't a guarantee.

How can I tell if an http.server subprocess is ready to receive requests?